# How to alter the return values in a list using spring AOP?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, aop

I am using a `search` method which is inside my `BaseRepository` to return a list based on the search conditions given. I am using the hibernate query for that. Some of the values in that list would be encrypted. So i want to alter that list before it returning using spring AOP. The `returnList` in the following code contains the `list` of search result which i accessed using AOP. I am using  a decrypt method to do decryption on the string in that list if the string is ecrypted. But how can i make changes in the following code to reflect in the exact result of search. I mean how the decryption done on the Aspect will reflect in original list.

```
@Aspect
@Service
public class DecryptionAspect {

    @AfterReturning(value="(execution(* search(..)) )" +
            "&& target(com.erp.core.repo.IBaseRepository) " +
            "&& args(..)",returning="returnList")
    public void decrypt(List returnList) throws Exception
    {

        Iterator itr = returnList.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            Object[] obj = (Object[]) itr.next();
            for(int i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
                if(obj[i]!=null)
                EncryptUtil.decrypt(obj[i].toString());


            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all strings need to be decrypted, you can just alter the arrays contained in the list:

```
@AfterReturning(value="(execution(* search(..)) )" +
        "&& target(com.erp.core.repo.IBaseRepository) " +
        "&& args(..)",returning="returnList")
public void decrypt(List returnList) throws Exception
{
    for (Object [] objs : (List<Object[]>) returnList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
            if (objs[i] instanceof String) {
                objs[i]= EncryptUtil.decrypt(objs[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This method is not triggering

Comment: @MohammedJavad Ah yes I removed the annotation, just add it again. See my updated answer.

Comment: I have added the annotation already. But also not triggering. But when i use my old method it is triggering. I don't know why.

Comment: OK. I guess AspectJ does not `List<Object[]> returnList` parameter signature, I reverted back to `List returnList` and added a cast. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to replace the element in the list "returnList".

```
@AfterReturning(value="(execution(* search(..)) )" +
        "&& target(com.erp.core.repo.IBaseRepository) " +
        "&& args(..)",returning="returnList")
public void decrypt(List returnList) throws Exception
{

    Iterator itr = returnList.iterator();
    int count=0;
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        Object[] obj = (Object[]) itr.next();
        Object[] newObjects = new Object[obj.length];
        for(int i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
            if(obj[i]!=null)
            String decryptedText = EncryptUtil.decrypt(obj[i].toString());
            newObjects[i] = decryptedText;
        }
        returnList.set(count,newObjects);
        count++;
    }
}
```